# Proper usage of input parameters in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

**Problem:**
I am trying to create a stored procedure that creates a Login with a username passed in as a parameter.  The parameter I pass in when I call the procedure is not used.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried calling my procedure with  `exec dbo.proc_add_user 'TestLogin'`.
I thought that calling it in this way would use "TestLogin" in place of `@arg1`.

Here is the stored procedure I am trying to create/alter:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_add_user]
(
    @arg1       varchar(255) = null
) AS

BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [@arg1] WITH PASSWORD=N'password' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON

   GRANT ALTER ANY LOGIN TO [@arg1]
   GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [@arg1]
   GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [@arg1]
   GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [@arg1]

END
```

Instead of creating a Login named "TestLogin", it creates a Login named "@arg1".  I have also tried setting `@arg1` to a declared varchar named `@userName`:

```
declare @userName varchar(255) = @arg1
BEGIN
CREATE LOGIN [@userName] WITH PASSWORD=N'password' ...
...
```

I get the same results with this method.  I will answer any questions as quick as possible, thanks.

Comment: well, you are trying to use dynamic SQL without actually making it dynamic

Comment: You'll have to create dynamic sql and run exec or sp_executesql

Comment: Thank you. I will research creating dynamic SQL procedures.  I was creating this procedure by looking at a similar procedure that passes in a varchar variable.

Comment: The example you were looking at is probably correct because it was a DML query. What you have posted here is not. These statements are DDL and as such you can't use variables like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its important to know that brackets are a form of quoting. It's only necessary if the column name contains spaces or punctuation or conflicts with a reserved word.

And your query is a dynamic sql, so ... you can try:

```sql
DECLARE @SQLString VARCHAR(500);

SET @SQLString = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @login_user + ' WITH PASSWORD=N''password'' MUST_CHANGE, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=ON, CHECK_POLICY=ON';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, N'@login_user varchar(255)', @login_user=@arg1;
```

See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) for details.

*Edit: Added a needed space before WITH*